# InfluxDB Query issue when measurement name have hyphen in it

Tags: java, influxdb

I am using Java and querying InfluxDb as shown below,

```
queryResult1 = influxDB.query(new Query("SELECT last(timestamp)  FROM vale" , eachDatabase));
```

This statement is working fine, but when the name have any of the special character for e.g. if measurement name is "vale-ab"  instead of vale, it won't work.

Error i am getting is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: {"error":"error parsing query: found -, expected ; at line 1, char 34"}
```

Any idea how can i escape measurement name inside the queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap your measurement with double quotes `"`.

**Bad:**

`select * from a-b`

> ERR: error parsing query: found -, expected ; at line 1, char 16

**Good:**

```
select * from "a-b"

 name: a-b
 time                tag1 value
 ----                ---- -----
 1434089562000000000 10i  5
```

I don't have `Java` installed on this machine but the code below should solve your problem.

```
queryResult1 = influxDB.query(new Query("SELECT last(timestamp)  FROM \"vale-vale\"" , eachDatabase));
```